# Linux : rpm -Uvh /rpms/* command not working as expected

Tags: linux, shell, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild

I wanted to upgrade some rpms in my Redhat/Linux based system. Some rpms might be already exist , some rpms are new to be installed and some rpms need to be upgrade to higher version using RPM upgrade command.

For example :

```
 I have placed rpms to be installed in folder <rpms>
      /rpms/X-1.rpm (This is already installed in system)
      /rpms/Y-1.rpm (This is NOT present in system. This is NEW)
      /rpms/Z-2.rpm (This is need to be upgraded to higher version available, 
                     Z-1.rpm is installed in system)
      /rpms/Q-1.rpm (This is already installed in system)
```

I am running below command in shell (.sh) file

```
$rpm -Uvh /rpms/*
```

It is showing below after execution

```
Preparing...            ################################### [100%]
    package X-1 is already installed
    package Q-1 is already installed
```

But it is not installing Y-1 and not able to upgrade to Z-2.

Please let me know what is needed to be done with `-Uvh` command to make it work? What would be best possible solution for above scenario?

Comment: You should really be using `yum` to handle upgrades (because it will handle updated dependencies, and because yum maintains metadata that isn't maintained by rpm).

Comment: yes, yum (or even dnf if available) would be better, if you still want to use rpm, you can try adding --replacepkgs, it will reinstall the already presnet packages, but at least, wont ignore the two other ones

Comment: I don't see any reason why people are behind to close question.Please don't follow crowd to close question. -Uvh command skipping installation and I don't find explaination in any RedHat doc. Hence I came here.

Comment: @larsks But rpm command should upgrade all rpms mentioned in directory but it is skipping new & upgraded rpm. It just find existing ones. I think that the issue with rpm command.

Comment: @OomphFortuity: I would expect the command to work, but is there no other output? normally `rpm` should give the reason why he is not installing those packages.

Comment: The `--replacepkgs` option is what you are looking for (but I'd simply move the rpms that are already installed out of the `rpms/` folder)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

rpm is refusing to run an improperly specified (because two requested packages are already installed) command, and hence skipping possible installs/upgrades.

You are expecting rpm to intuit what you meant by a command.

Basically there is no way for rpm to accurately figure what was intended.

Did you mean to reinstall packages already installed (and possibly modified/damaged) or not? (Use --force or --reinstall to reinstall packages already installed).

Did you want to upgrade only already installed packages, ignoring uninstalled packages? (Use --freshen.)

Did you wish rpm to assume that packages in the --upgrade arg list to be installed even though there is no previous version to upgrade (as requested)?

"Do What I Mean" (DWIM) behavior cannot be implemented to everyone's satisfaction. RPM takes a conservative approach and exits, not installing Y-1 and not upgrading Z-2, basic allying doing nothing and returning an error code.